# $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1+ (\frac{2\pi n}{\beta})^{-2} )^{-1} = \frac{\beta}{2 \sinh(\frac{\beta}{2})}$

Tags: products

\begin{align}
\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(1+ (\frac{2\pi n}{\beta})^{-2} \right)^{-1} = \frac{\beta}{2 \sinh(\frac{\beta}{2})}
\end{align}
I'd like to prove the following products. 
Can you give me some explicit calculation for this? 
I try to expand all the term and make exponential, but eventually i failed.

Above products is convergent product (not zeta-function regularized products).

Comment: See [Basel problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the perspective of Basel problem

\begin{align}
&\sin(x) = x- \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} + \cdots \\
& \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1- \frac{x^2}{3!} + \frac{x^4}{5!} + \cdots
\end{align}
Euler argue that the solution of $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ is $\pm n\pi$ for $ n=1,2,3...$ so 
\begin{align}
\frac{\sin(x)}{x} &= (1-\frac{x}{\pi})(1+\frac{x}{\pi})(1-\frac{x}{2\pi})(1+\frac{x}{2\pi})\cdots \\
& = (1- \frac{x^2}{\pi^2})(1-\frac{x^2}{4\pi^2}) \cdots = \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1- (\frac{x}{n\pi})^2)
\end{align}

using
\begin{align}
& \sinh(x) = -i \sin(ix)
\end{align}

\begin{align} 
\frac{\sinh(x)}{x}=\frac{\sin(ix)}{ix}= \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1- (\frac{ix}{n\pi})^2)
=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+ (\frac{x}{n\pi})^2)
\end{align}